# Swift: "Fatal error: newElements.underestimatedCount was an overestimate" - what does this error mean?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, fatal-error

I have a tableView and it has data source as a computed array **allItems**:

```
var pendingItems: [Item] = []      
var loadingItems: [Item] = []      
var processedItems: [Item] = []

var allItems: [Item] {
        return processedItems + loadingItems + pendingItems
    }
```

Sometimes, while running the app I get this error:
**Thread 1: Fatal error: newElements.underestimatedCount was an overestimate**.

It looks like it occurs when I try to reach the element by its index in this function:

```
    func getCellContent(at index: Int) -> (url: String, status: String) {
        return (url: queue.allItems[index].url, status: queue.allItems[index].status.description)
    }
```

Here is a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9miuyiz1em56mk/Screen%20Shot%202019-04-12%20at%202.06.25%20PM.png?dl=1

Can somebody explain why this happens? I'd really appreciate any help!

**Data Source methods** (from view controller):

```
extension WebSearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return presenter.getNumberOfRows()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WebPageTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! WebPageTableViewCell
        let (url, status) = presenter.getCellContent(at: indexPath.row)
        cell.addressLabel.text = url
        cell.statusLabel.text = status
        return cell
    }
}
```

Helping methods from presenter:

```
    func getNumberOfRows() -> Int {
        return queue.allItems.count
    }

    func getCellContent(at index: Int) -> (url: String, status: String) {
        return (url: queue.allItems[index].url, status: queue.allItems[index].status.description)
    }
```

This is my `Item`:

```
class WebPage: NSObject {
    var url: String
    var status: URLStatus

    init(url: String, status: URLStatus = .unchecked) {
        self.url = url
        self.status = status
    }

    func changeStatus(to newStatus: URLStatus) {
        self.status = newStatus
    }

    static func == (lhs: WebPage, rhs: WebPage) -> Bool {
        return lhs.url == rhs.url
    }
}
```

Comment: Everytime you call allItems you will create a new array by combining 3 arrays, wouldn't it at least be better in getCellContent to use a local variable? `let all = allItems`

Comment: add celforrow and numberofrows delegates code

Comment: @dahiya_boy, I've added data source methods

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I decided to make a computed variable because it's is always changing. I remove elements from **pendingItems**, add them to **loadingItems** and then to **processedItems** (as soon as they change their statuses). This is why allItems array is always different.  I thought that it'd be non-efficient to iterate over one huge array any time I need a specific item. Is there any better way to organize elements with different statuses?

Comment: @AlinaVas Can you show `Item ` model pls.

Comment: @dahiya_boy, yes, please. I added. Item is actually a generic placeholder type name. I use a WebPage class for it.

Comment: @AlinaVas What is the presenter.getNumberOfRows()

Comment: @dahiya_boy, I call it in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method. it returns a count value of the allItems array

Comment: can you try exception break point. and add xcode crash pls.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I meant to create a local variable so you only needed to access the computed property once

Comment: @AlinaVas Try this also `queue.getAllItems().underestimatedCount` (Not sure it does work but you can try)

Comment: @dahiya_boy, seems like replacing "count" with "underestimatedCount" in getNumberOfRows method actually solved the problem. At least I haven't had any error ever since. Could you, please, explain what is underestimatedCount for? Anyway, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I'm sorry, probably I still don't get your point, but creating a local variable inside getCellContent would still mean creating an array (`let all = allItems`) every time this method is called. Am I wrong?

Comment: No that is correct but now your creating it twice for each call

Comment: @AlinaVas does your issue solved ??

Comment: @dahiya_boy, unfortunately, today I'm getting the same error, with underestimadedCount

Comment: @AlinaVas You got error or your app has been crashed?

Comment: @dahiya_boy, from time to time I'm getting **Fatal error: newElements.underestimatedCount was an overestimate** or even **index is out of range**. And, of course, the app crashes. This is very inconsistent. Probably it has something to do with the fact that I use operation queues for performing operations concurrently.

Comment: @AlinaVas check the indexpath at which it crashed and check the data at same index in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine and its hard to say root cause of error. Here is some key features about `underestimatedCount` hope it helps for knowledge purpose.

The `underestimatedCount` promises the count of collection will not be the greater than the number of elements in sequence and in the **sequence protocol** default value is zero. [Check](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L655)

```
@inlinable
  public var underestimatedCount: Int {
    return 0
  }
```

Moreover, in the **collection protocol** its default value is same as count. [Check](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1212)

```
@inlinable
  public var underestimatedCount: Int {
    // TODO: swift-3-indexing-model - review the following
    return count
  }
```

Therefore, because of this default implementation, using a **Collection's** `underestimatedCount` directly is definitely less common than using a **Sequence's**, as Collection guarantees non-destructive iteration, and in most cases `underestimatedCount` will just return the `count`.

Although, of course, custom collection types could provide their own implementation of `underestimatedCount` – giving a lower bound of how many elements they contain, in a possibly more efficient way than their `count` implementation, which could potentially be useful.